# Can someone tell me how to create in java an array of n number of threads in a thread group?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, synchronization, threadgroup

I've been trying for some time to find some examples or explenations of java how to create an array of n threads that are part of some threadgroup, so if anyone knows something more please explain, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use ThreadGroup at all?  Do you actually need it?  Maybe all you really need is an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) that you can submit your runnables and callables to.

Being new, you might also want to take a look at [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).  It's almost like a thread, except a Callable returns a value.  When you submit a callable, you get back a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object, which is like a promise to get the value from the callable.

Comment: Personally, I like creating executor services.  You don't actually create threads yourself, you create Runnables and let the executor deals with running it.  It's a nice way of throttling threads, too.

Comment: Its also a nice way of creating queuing tasks and shutting down the pool.

Answer (score 4):

Sure.  You can instantiate a `ThreadGroup` and just pass it into the `Thread` constructor:

```
  ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup("somename");
  Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i] = new Thread(threadGroup, someRunnable);
  }
  ...
```